# Why are my input values not binding to my viewmodel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-2.0

I am trying to pass input values to an array within my viewmodel. Then loop through the values and save the new changes in each however, every time I submit, the model values come in as null except for one value(duration). I've tried changing the names and id's but to avail.

View

```
@{
    var SMs = ((List<Stage_Media>)ViewBag.Stage_Media);
}
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="card card-alt3">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h3><strong>Show Order</strong></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <table class="dd table" id="show_list">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Order</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Path</th>
                    <th>Upload Date</th>
                    <th>Duration (Min:Sec)</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            @if (SMs.Count() > 0)
            {
                <tbody class="dd-list">
                    @foreach (var sm in SMs.OrderBy(sm => sm.order))
                    {
                        <tr class="dd-item dd3-item" data-id="@sm.media.id" data-duration="@sm.duration">
                            <td class="dd-handle dd3-handle"></td>
                            <td class="dd3-content">@sm.order</td>
                            <td class="dd3-content">@sm.media.name</td>
                            <td class="dd3-content">@sm.media.ext</td>
                            <td class="dd3-content">@sm.media.uploaded</td>
                            <td class="dd3-content">
                                @if (sm.media.ext == "jpg" || sm.media.ext == "png")
                                {
                                    <input name="sm_duration" id="sm.duration" placeholder = "mm:ss"
                                        value = @(sm.duration != null ? TimeSpan.FromTicks((long)@sm.duration).ToString(@"m\:ss", null) : "00:10") />
                                }
                                <input name="sm_start_date" id="sm.start_date" type="date" />
                                <input name="sm_end_date" id="sm.end_date" type="date" />
                                <select name="sm_occurrence">
                                    <option default value=Everyday>Every day</option>
                                    <option value="Bi-Weekly">Bi-Weekly</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 15%">
                                <div class="row align-items-center align-middle" style="margin: 0; height: 6em; max-height: 6em">
                                    @if (sm.media.ext == "mp4" || sm.media.ext == "mov" || sm.media.ext == "mkv")
                                {
                                    <video id="video" src="/api/media?media_id=@sm.media.id" style="object-fit: cover; width: 100%; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;" autoplay muted playsinline loop></video>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <img id="image" src="/api/media?media_id=@sm.media.id" style="width: 100%; height:100%; object-fit: contain;">
                                }
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            }
            else
            {
                <tbody class="dd-empty">
                    <tr class="dd-placeholder">
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <button type="button" name="Save" onclick="return saveStage(@ViewBag.Branch_id, 
             @ViewBag.Stage.id);" class="btn btn-alt1">Save Stage</button>
        <button type="button" name="Delete" onclick="return deleteStage(@ViewBag.Stage.id);" 
            class="btn btn-alt1">Delete Stage</button>
    <a name="View" href="/home/view?stage_id=@ViewBag.Stage.id" class="btn btn-alt1">View</a>
</div>
```

ViewModel

```
public class SaveStage_ViewModel
{
    public int stage_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public File[] ids { get; set; }

    public class File
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{mm\\:ss}")]
        [Display(Name = "Duration")]
        public string duration { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
        public DateTime? start_date { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "End Date")]
        public DateTime? end_date { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Occurence")]
        public string occurrence { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Model

```
public class Stage_Media
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int stage_id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("stage_id")]
    public Stage stage { get; set; }
    public int media_id { get; set; }
    public long? duration { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("media_id")]
    public Media media { get; set; }
    public int order { get; set; }
    public DateTime? start_date { get; set; }
    public DateTime? end_date { get; set; }
    public string occurrence { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string SaveStage(SaveStage_ViewModel model)
    {
        using (var c = new Context())
        {
            var stage = c.Stage.Find(model.stage_id);
            stage.name = model.name;
            stage.modified = DateTime.Now;
            stage.modified_by = User.Identity.Name;

            var sml = new List<Stage_Media>();
            for (var i = 0; i < model.ids.Count(); i++)
            {
                var sm = new Stage_Media();
                sm.stage_id = model.stage_id;
                sm.media_id = model.ids[i].id;
                sm.start_date = model.ids[i].start_date;
                sm.end_date = model.ids[i].start_date;
                sm.occurrence = model.ids[i].occurrence;
                sm.order = i + 1;
                sm.duration = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.ids[i].duration) ? (long?)TimeSpan.ParseExact(model.ids[i].duration, @"m\:ss", null).Ticks : null;

                sml.Add(sm);
            }

            c.Stage.Update(stage);
            c.Stage_Media.RemoveRange(c.Stage_Media.Where(smr => smr.stage_id == model.stage_id));
            c.Stage_Media.AddRange(sml);
            c.SaveChanges();
        }

        return $"Stage Save Successful";
    }
```

Comment: Where do you call your view?  Where do you set your `ViewBag.*` property?

Answer (score 2):

> Every time I submit, the model values come in as null except for one
> value(duration). I've tried changing the names and id's but to avail.

Actually, it would be more convenient if you would have shared your page initialization code snippet where you have set your `@ViewBag.Branch_id` value and this is one of the reason of your null value on submit.

I have tried to similate your issue and worked as expected. Here is the sample for your reference how I have tested the scenario.

Demo Model:

```
public class SaveStage_ViewModel
    {
        public int stage_id { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }

    }

    public class Stage_Media
    {
        public int Branch_id { get; set; }
        public int stage_id { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller:

```
public class NullViewModelController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            Stage_Media stage_Media = new Stage_Media();
            stage_Media.Branch_id = 101;    
            stage_Media.stage_id = 404;
            ViewBag.Stage_Media = stage_Media;
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public string SaveStage(SaveStage_ViewModel model)
        {
            return $"Stage Id:{model.stage_id} and branch Id : {model.Id} has been Saved Successfully";
        }
    }
```

**Note:**  I have assigned demo value on  ViewBag.Stage_Media while loading index view.

View:

```
@{
    var SMs = (Stage_Media)ViewBag.Stage_Media);
}

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <button type="button" name="Save" onclick="return saveStage(@SMs.Branch_id,
                 @SMs.stage_id);" class="btn btn-success">
                Save Stage
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <strong><span id="appendHere"></span></strong></>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function saveStage(branchId, stageId) {
    
            var valueFromViewModel = {
                stage_id: stageId,
                Id: branchId
            }
    
            var requestUrl = '@Url.Action("SaveStage", "YourControllerName")';
    
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: requestUrl,
                data: { model: valueFromViewModel },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $("#appendHere").html(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert('Data was not sent to backend!');
                }
            });
    
        }
    </script>
```

**Note:** You either can pass value using `saveStage(@SMs.Branch_id, @SMs.stage_id);` or `saveStage(@ViewBag.Stage_Media.Branch_id, @@ViewBag.Stage_Media.stage_id);` Both will work accordingly. I have used single model but you can use List and pass the index value you want.

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Take Ways:** Check your `@Viewbag` data first if that has assigned correctly. On top of this, double check your `saveStage` function if the value has been passed as expected. You can use browser network trace and console. You may [refer to this official link for debugging assistance.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/network/#open-the-network-tool) Furthermore, you can have a [look at this official sample.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: Nice, this was another developers work that I was trying to add some features to. After looking at your example I went back and found the code snipet you mentioned and now everything works!

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am glad that resolve your issue.  Is there anything else that you need assistance on?